# Using git and svn

Tags: git, svn

I have been trying to solve this problem on my own. However I did not find a solution that really works. All my attempts ended with conflicts, many rebases, etc. etc.

So, I have the following setup:

Git is my main CVS for all my projects.

For one of the projects I am using the wp7 silverlight toolkit from codeplex.com. 
However for my project I need to change some lines of code in the toolkit.

So, I would like to have the following scenario:

- In Git I would need to have a clone of the SVN repo from codeplex.
  So, I could easily work on it.(Btw the SVN repo is read-only)
- However, from time to time I would need to fetch the latest updates
  from the SVN repo.

How can I accomplish this scenario?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would probably use `git-svn` and make a separate repo for the Silverlight toolkit, and then in your Git repo use it as a `submodule`.

Comment: @basicxman I already tried that. However, the problems appear when I fetch updates from the SVN repo. Conflicts with logs and history.

Answer (score 1):

Within your project could the toolkit be in a subfolder which is managed by svn?

A simplistic approach (which misses out the opportunity to import the svn version history git-svn which basicxman mentions) would be to manage the whole project using git including the contents of the folders updated by svn.  You may wish to exclude the .svn directories through.

Try adding a line to  .git/info/exclude for your project to ignore files or folders called .svn

Comment: Thank you, that is one way of solving this issue. However I would like to use git for the whole scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You are making changes to the codeplex code. Make those changes on a branch. Keep master up to date with the codeplex svn repo using git-svn. After an update, merge master into your changes branch.

Then share your codeplex repo with your main repo as a submodule as suggested before.